# Showing that the functions $\sqrt{2x}\exp(2\pi inx^2)$ form a complete orthonormal system for $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

How do I show that the functions

$$g_n(x) :=\sqrt{2x}\exp(2\pi inx^2)$$

where $n$ is a integer, are a complete orthonormal set in $L^2([0, 1])$?

I am relatively new to this and need some help getting started.

Comment: Start with the orthogonality relation; use the scalar product on $L^2[0,1]$ to show that $\langle g_n, g_m\rangle=\delta_{nm}$.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematics.SE! A word or two about my edit. Our conventions on politeness are a bit different from usual: Due to the user information "rectangle" on the bottom right of your post, there is no need to decorate your questions with salutations or "Thanks in advance". Cheers, and enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\langle g_n, g_n\rangle =\int_{0}^{1}2x\exp(2\pi inx^2-2\pi i n x^2)dx$$

by definition of the scalar product $\langle,\rangle$ on $L^2([0,1])$. Then

$$\langle g_n, g_n\rangle = \int_{0}^{1}2xdx=2\frac{1}{2}x^2|^{1}_0=1,$$

for all $n$.

Now we consider 
$$\langle g_n, g_m\rangle =\int_{0}^{1}2x\exp(2\pi inx^2-2\pi i mx^2)dx=
\int_{0}^{1}2x\exp(2\pi i(n-m)x^2)dx$$

with $m\neq n$. Using

$$\frac{d}{dx}\exp(2\pi i(n-m)x^2)=4\pi i(n-m)x\exp(2\pi i(n-m)x^2)$$

we arrive at

$$\langle g_n, g_m\rangle =\frac{2}{4\pi i(n-m)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}\exp(2\pi i(n-m)x^2)dx=\frac{1}{2\pi i(n-m)}\exp(2\pi i(n-m)x^2)|^{1}_{0}=
\frac{1}{2\pi i(n-m)}[\exp(2\pi i(n-m))-1]=0,$$

because $q:=n-m\in\mathbb Z$ and $\exp(2\pi i q)=1$.

Comment: Where did the x^2 go in the exp? need a little more help to compute the last=)

Comment: A typo, I correct it right now. Thanks.

Comment: thank you, I still dont get it though :/ I guess I must show that <g_n,g_m>=0 for all m=#n.

Comment: Exactly, this is correct. I add some more details in the answer.

Comment: I did the variable substitution x^2=t in the last integral and then it popped out to be 0. What about the completness?

Comment: Completeness is more involved. You have to prove that if $f\in L^2([0,1])$ is orthogonal to all $g_n$, then $f=0$. This criterium comes from prop.3.8 (part 4) ) in the notes http://warwickmaths.org/files/fourier.pdf  In the same reference you can read the proof of Thm. 4.1. and adapt it to your specific case. Feel free to flag/upvote the answer above if you accept it.